# Multiple errors in my code and I don't understand

Tags: c

Currently trying to make a function that counts the number of any given words in the U.S. Constitution. On initial build, it didn't let me know about any warnings or errors until I tried to run it, and then there were many errors that didn't make sense. I'm not very good at coding, and am somewhat frustrated.

The code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_WORD_LENGTH 32
#define MIN_WORD_LENGTH 5

int main() {
    FILE *file = fopen("F:\\The_US_Constitution.txt", "r");
    char word[32];
    const char *line;
    const char *start = NULL;
    int count = 0;

    while(strlen(word) < MIN_WORD_LENGTH || strlen(word) > MAX_WORD_LENGTH);
    printf("Enter a word: ");
    scanf("&s",word);

    if(strlen(word) >= MIN_WORD_LENGTH && strlen(word) <= MAX_WORD_LENGTH)
        while((word = fgetc(file)) != EOF){
                if (word == '\n')
                    count++;
            }
        return count;

        fclose("F:\\The_US_Constitution.txt");
        if(count > 0)
            printf("The word ''",word,"''was found %d times in the US Constitution", count);
        else
            printf("The word ''", word, "''was not found in the US Constitution");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

1. FILE *file = ... it says it's an unused variable? I don't think that file needs to be defined and when I tried to define it elsewhere, it said it was still an unused variable.
2. The code says that both 'line' and 'start' are unused variables in the same lines I'm trying to define them on.
3. while(strlen(word) < MIN_WORD_LENGTH ... implicit declaration of function strlen...I don't know what I did wrong here. I was trying to make a condition that would make the program ask the question again if the character length of the inputted word was outside those parameters.
4. scanf("%s", word); - it says that there are too many arguments for this. I thought I only have one argument on this line?
5. if(strlen(word))...incompatible declaration of function strlen. Again, I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.
6. if(word == \n); passing argument of fclose from incompatible pointer type - why is this showing up here?
7. 2 warnings about "too many arguments for format" with two of my brackets...

and then a lot of syntax errors.

I feel incompetent...I don't know why these errors are showing up or how to fix them.

Comment: You have a few minor problems, your includes are missing stdio.h and string.h , this line  printf("The word ''",word,"''was found %d times in the US Co.. is wrong because you cannot concatenate words in that way in C, what you can is use sprintf, example here : sprintf( tempstring,"The word %s was found %d times in the US Constitution",word, count);
               puts(tempstring); then there is this line :while((word = fgetc(file)) != EOF) here you believe you get the word, but you are using fgetc that gets only a char, just fix one problem at a time, read the error messages. Have fun.

Comment: You have many major issues. The first two are that `*file` is unused because after declaring it, it is never referenced again in the code, which means it's a do-nothing declaration. You also `fopen` a file, but then never access that file again, but instead try to `fclose` a string variable instead of the `*file` you opened. With that being said, this is not a *Here's my numbered list of questions* site. This is a *question and answer* site - note that *question* is singular. If you have multiple things to ask, you need to create multiple questions in order to ask them, not dump them all here.

Comment: `strlen(word)` can never equal `MAX_WORD_LENGTH` unless you declare `char word[MAX_WORD_LENGTH + 1];`

Comment: Another general note, file I/O is one of the slowest operations. If you are asking for a word to search and then repeatedly reading from the file each time looking for a match, that is less than optimal or efficient. (but not bad for an exercise -- plus the Constitution is short ~26.5K bytes so no noticeable penalty). However, in practice you would either want to store the contents of the file in memory, or better, simply `mmap` (*memory map*) the file and be able to search through the memory any number of times without triggering any additional file I/O.

Comment: You may find [Word Search mmap'ed File](https://pastebin.com/JFcGfCqm) helpful there. Simply provide the name of the file to search as the first argument (e.g. `argv[1]`). For example in the Constitution, `"Meeting"` occurs 3-times, `"King"` occurs once and there is no room for `"Incompetent"` in the Constitution.

Answer (score 1):

1. The compiler warns about a unused variable, because the compiler doesn't see that you use the variable `file` anywhere else.
2. The only occurrence of `line` and `start` variables is the declaration. You don't use them anywhere else. Hence the warning.
3. To use `strlen()` function you have forward declare it by `#include <string.h>` including the relevant header file. For more infomration see [cppreference strlen](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen).
4. Your code has `scanf("&s",word);`, not `scanf("%s",word);`. Because the `&s` does not expect an argument, the compiler warns you about it.
5. You forgot to include relevant header as in point 3.
6. `fclose()` function should be passed a pointer to `FILE`, not a string containing the filepath. Ie. most probably you meant `fclose(file)` - to close the `FILE` pointer as returned by the call to `fopen()`.
7. Your usage of `printf` is invalid. To print the word use the `%s` printf format specifier in the format string. For more information you could see [cppreference printf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Your code also:

- Accesses uninitialized memory in the first occurence of `strlen(word)` inside the first `while` loop.
- And the loop `while(strlen(word) < MIN_WORD_LENGTH || strlen(word) > MAX_WORD_LENGTH);` does nothing of significance - it is either an endless loop or not.
- `word = fgetc(file)` assigns to an array type, which is impossible (and makes no sense). The return value of [`fgetc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) function is `int` - you should save it in an `int` variable.
- `word == '\n'` is comparing an address of an array to a character.
- Your code will return from `main` after the `return count;` and not execute the code below.
- Has no error handling.

I believe your code has too many errors for me to help you. Stackoverflow is not a good place for beginners - I believe it's a forum to ask a specific programming questions, not to explain the intricacies with basic usage of the language. To ease and speed up your adventure into the C programming language I suggest you start with much more simpler task and examples, that could help you into learning experience with the language and guide you on. Start small, end big.

Comment: See my comment under original question -- that's another to add.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting errors that are somewhat different from what you describe. To fix the implicit declaration errors, you need more header files:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
```

> FILE *file = ... it says it's an unused variable? I don't think that file needs to be defined and when I tried to define it elsewhere, it said it was still an unused variable.

I got a completely different error saying that `FILE` is undeclared. Fixed with the above `#include`s.

> The code says that both 'line' and 'start' are unused variables in the same lines I'm trying to define them on.

This error basically means what it says. You probably forgot to use these variables in your algorithm. If you really don't need them, comment them out.

> scanf("%s", word); - it says that there are too many arguments for this. I thought I only have one argument on this line?

Your actual code has a `&` where there should be a `%`.

> if(word == \n); passing argument of fclose from incompatible pointer type - why is this showing up here?

For me, this error is "comparison between pointer and integer". You declare `word` as an array, but you seem to treat it as both that and a character.

> 2 warnings about "too many arguments for format" with two of my brackets...

`printf` does not simply print its arguments. Its first argument must be a format string which includes `%` codes. Each additional argument corresponds to one of those `%` codes. Example:

```
printf("The word ''%s''was found %d times in the US Constitution", word, count);
```